# Python reading mail accounts from txt file

Tags: python-2.7

Python...

I have a file of e-mail addresses and i need to create a script to import all these addresses as accounts, so there is some text manipulation going on, and i need to learn more python.
the file is in the form of

user1@domain1.co.uk 
user1@domain2.com 
user2@domain4.com 
user3@domain4.com

This is basically a user name and a domain name that i need to create an account name (same as user) and domain, and e-mail address, with some other date/file path variables into an import file.  once the user and domain have been assigned to variables they can be printed to a file with some other data to create and import list/script.  Then use the import file to create a list of accounts on a new mail server, without going through all 128k of them one by one.
So.  How do i read each line of the file (128,000 entries) one at a time, to put each user name into a variable followed by corresponding domain into an array / tuple / list/ dict ?  to then add the date and some other file path stuff to build an account name with email address from the two variables and append the output to a new file, but doing this per-line before looping onto the next line and repeating??

somthing along the lines of

make output file 
read file line 1 and put the user and domain into variables 
print user print domain print (otherstuff) print user@domain

append each output loop to same new file (not original) 
loop to next line of file and repeat
 
continue to EOF (128k lines later) 
to make one big file to import mail accounts and details for each, 
(possibly split output file to smaller chunks for import stability 100 entries per-file?)

so far i have

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time;

input = open('/home/adam/Downloads/mailaccounts.txt', 'r')
fileoutput = open('/tmp/domaintest.txt', 'a' 'w')
sql1 = "INSERT INTO mailbox (username, password, name, storagebasedirectory, maildir, quota, domain, active)"
password = "88888888"
storage_base_directory = '/var/vmail/vmail1'
localtime = time.localtime(time.time())
localtime = localtime[0], ".", localtime[1], ".", localtime[2], ".", localtime[3], ".", localtime[4], ".", localtime[5]
localtime = ''.join(map(str, localtime))
for line in input:
    email = line
    user = line.split("@")[0]
    domain = line.split("@")[1]
    fileoutput.write(domain)
```

now the out file has characters

```
^@d^@o^@m^@a^@i^@n^@1^@.^@c^@o.^@u^@k^@^M^@
```

that do not appear with the print command when testing from command line

```
domain1.co.uk
```

anyone any ideas?

Comment: Here's a regex to match your multiline text file. https://gist.github.com/3624220 Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing 'a' 'w' option with 'a+' as following

```
fileoutput = open('/tmp/domaintest.txt', 'a+')
```

after this your script is working good and getting

```
domain1.co.uk 
domain2.com 
domain4.com 
domain4.com
```

as output in output file